# Info Path get Page Properties

Tags: infopath

I have created a workflow in SharePoint Designer. In which I need to modifiy workflow association form. I need certain fields to be pre-populated. These fields are listed in Page Properties.

One of the field is a site column and it is taxonomy column. I am not sure how to fetch an taxonomy field, in the infopath as pre-populated field.